# How can I inform the user that a remote API failed due to connectivity issues?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have an app where a user has to sign into his/her account. The app makes API calls to our backend server, but when the user doesn't have Internet, the app crashes when trying to log in.

Will apple reject my app if it crashes due to no internet? It works perfectly fine (crash free) when the user has internet. If they do, how do I display a `UIAlertView` whenever the app tries to make an api call to let the user know that the action failed because of internet connectivity issues?

Comment: Of course it will be rejected. Crashes are bad user experience.

Comment: I hope they will .. in any case, please ask and *focus* on the real question: i.e. "How can I inform the user that a remote API failed due to connectivity issues?"

Comment: @rmaddy you are definitely right, thanks for giving me a perfect way to word the more important question.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to use "Reachability" to check for an Internet connection. If there is no connection, don't even attempt to make any calls to the Internet. Alert the user they need access to continue.

Regardless of that though, your app shouldn't crash due to no Internet. Why is it crashing? Write better code that handles unexpected results.